# Is it enough to remove the HTML elements containing tracks or do they need to be detached first in Twilio Programmable Video?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twilio

I'm using Vue.js and I keep track of all Participants in a Vue data array called `participants`. Initially when a Participant connects, I push them into this array, which with the help of v-for, will produce the to-be container for the Participant's media. Once the container is ready, I use the ref to locate it and do `track.attach()` to add the Participant's tracks to it.

Upon removal, is there any specific reason to use `track.detach()` versus simply removing the Participant from the `participants` array in my case, leading to the destruction of the HTML element containing the tracks? Does this have any effect on any events fired or does it cause problems with disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call detach there is a bit more work that gets done, mainly the removing of the `mediaStreamTrack` from a `MediaStream` object the track keeps track of. You can see [the code for detaching the track here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/master/lib/media/track/mediatrack.js#L240-L259).

I am not sure on this, but as long as the track itself is eventually discarded then the `mediaStreamTrack` and `MediaStream` will also be discarded and there won't be a memory leak. It doesn't have, as far as I know, any effects on disconnecting or other events.

Comment: Nice! And thank you for sharing the detaching code!